# appendRow in 2 If Statements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following problem. I want to have a value written to a line when a certain condition is met. The whole thing works currently also here my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2"; 
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1000,1); 
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && range != "") {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();

    if (val != "") {
      let rowToAdd = [val, "", currentDate, ""]
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd);
      ui.alert("Test2");
    } 

    if (val === ""){
      let rowToAdd = ["", "", "", currentDate]
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd);
      ui.alert("Test3");
    }
  }
}
```

I want the second If statement to put the value in the same line as in the first If statement, so that no new line is created. Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: Can I ask you about `I want the second If statement to put the value in the same line as in the first If statement, so that no new line is created.`? About `the same line as in the first If statement`, how do you check this? For example, when there are several rows by `the first If statement`, where do you want to put the value as `the same line as in the first If statement`?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem too, I don't really know how to tie the line to it so that it works with multiple lines. the whole thing should be used as a time tracker. The first if statement should set the start time and the second if statement the "end time"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `how to tie the line to it so that it works with multiple lines`, I cannot understand about your goal. So in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample situation including the input and output you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: The main task is to measure time. Someone enters a cell, then this time (start time) should be entered in another worksheet with the first if statement. Should he "unsubscribe" again, i.e. empty the cell, the currentdate should also be written next to the start time.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following replying,

> I don't really know how to tie the line to it so that it works with multiple lines. the whole thing should be used as a time tracker. The first if statement should set the start time and the second if statement the "end time"

> The main task is to measure time. Someone enters a cell, then this time (start time) should be entered in another worksheet with the first if statement. Should he "unsubscribe" again, i.e. empty the cell, the currentdate should also be written next to the start time.

In this case, I thought that the current last row might be the cell you want to put the values of `["", "", "", currentDate]`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `addTimestamp` as follows.

```
function addTimestamp(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2";
  var ss = e.source;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1000, 1);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && range != "") {
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();
    if (val != "") {
      let rowToAdd = [val, "", currentDate, ""]
      ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd);
      ui.alert("Test2");
    } else {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 4).setValue(currentDate);
      ui.alert("Test3");
    }
  }
}
```

- As the additional modification point, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be replaced with `e.source` using the event object.

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, and that's exactly what I was looking for. However, with the help of your code I still have the following problem. If two people enter each other, only the person below will enter the last date when deleting the two cells.

Comment: You're right, I'll put that again in a new question. I just need to wait 2 Days.

Comment: @LamaFahrrad Thank you for your response. When I find your new question, I would like to think of the solution.